# Controlling SVG Rectangle height and width with variables in JS

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to create rectangles based on variable height and width in JavaScript. Here is the original code
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_rect

that I I have tried to modify for variable height but it is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var h=50
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height=`${h}` style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried other variations like `+ h +` and `${h}` but none are working and rectangle does not show up

Comment: @BasvanderLinden What is the correct syntax that I can try in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax is invalid.

There are multiple ways to go about doing this.

You could dynamically set the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of the `body` using [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    var h = 50;

    document.body.innerHTML += `
      <svg width="400" height="110">
        <rect width="300" height=${h} style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
      </svg>
    `;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you could give the `rect` element an id and use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set the `height` attribute of the `rect`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect id="rect" width="300" height="300" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
  </svg>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("rect").setAttribute("height", 50);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are also a lot of templating engines that allow you to do this in a more declarative way, but these are too many to mention all here so you can google that if you're interested.

**Update**

Triggering change of attribute based on event:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <svg width="400" height="110">
      <rect id="rect" width="300" height="300" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
      </svg>
      <script>
        const rect = document.getElementById("rect");
        rect.onmouseover = function () {
            rect.setAttribute("height", 50);
        };
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can this be wrapped inside a function which accepts height as an argument?

Comment: Sure you can, what should be the trigger?

Comment: you mean argument? if so, height. Trigger could be mouse over or hover if I understand you

Comment: See updated answer. The function in the last example doesn't take an argument, because it doesn't need to here. But you could pass an argument to the anonymous function if you want, doesn't make sense in this example.

Comment: Thanks @Bas van der Linden